# Boost asio receive HTTP POST?

Tags: php, c++, boost-asio

Is it possible for one PHP script to post data to a c++, boost asio program using HTTP?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You say you know how to download the data. At the same time you're asking how to receive the data. But downloading is receiving. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I want the PHP to post them in C++

Comment: a port can be bound to one process at a time. so if you've got apache on 80/443, then your app can't use them directly.

Comment: @Luka: Then this is a PHP question, not a C++ question. The fact that the client is written in C++ is irrelevant here. That's what protocols like HTTP are for.

Comment: `boost-asio` is perfectly capable of speaking any user specified protocol over TCP, but if you want to use ports that are already in use by any other applications that will not work.

Comment: I hope now the question makes sense. Tagged with PHP also. This is mainly a C++ question. Making a POST with PHP is easy, but reading a POST from c++? Is this possible?

Comment: @Chad: but when I download stuff from a url with boost asio I use port 80. How does this work, when Apache is open?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/client/sync_client.cpp

Comment: "Using port 80" is a but of an oversimplification. When you download from some server "using port 80" that remote process is listening on port 80.  The actual data comes locally to you over an OS defined port.  Only one process can effectively "listen" on a port at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is perfectly capable of communicating with other servers / programs using POST. Check out  [cURL here](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) for more details on how to do it.

Another alternative is to use FSock. Have a look at [this command](https://www.php.net/fsockopen) for establishing a connection.

Those links should get you started. If you have any trouble getting them working post back with a specific question.